# MySql Best Practices: List/Array in Single Field, Multiple Fields, or Second Table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Okay, I'm going to be dealing with about 1,000,000 items which will be shared by a limited number of stores. The number of stores are limited to about 5, but that could potentially change. The products table has about 60 to 70 fields already to manage.

These are three methods I am considering:

1. Implode the values into a small varchar, say about 20 characters long, with a delimiter can store about 10 stores to associate the product with. The MySQL select can use LIKE '%|2|%' to match any products with store ID 2.

   There are numerous discussions on using MySQL Procedures, too.

   **Pros**: One field, easy to accommodate more stores, less memory used?

   **Cons**: Text search, takes longer?
2. It would be easiest and probably best to just create a TINYINT (1) and a new field for each. The problem is, if new stores are added, new fields will have to be added, altering millions of products.

   **Pros**: Easy to select

   **Cons**: Adding stores requires altering the table structure, more fields to manage - what if they have 20 stores down the line (future-proofing)
3. The standard response I would expect is to use a linking table to associate the products with the stores, just a two field table. My concern is if most products are used by most stores, then suddenly, there could be about 5 million rows in that table.

   I could break the link tables out to reduce their row count, for example by first letter of the product name and have 26 link tables.

   **Pros**: LEFT JOIN is easy to use

   **Cons**: Almost every query would need to search through the 5 million link tables, unless broken out

I really should but together some tests to figure out the best response/processing times, but that would take some time in itsef. I'm interested to hear what your best solution would be for keeping gobs of data future-proof for more stores and stored with efficiently.

Comment: The third approach is the best. Also, 5 million rows is nothing to worry about provided you use adequate constraints and indexes

Comment: I imagine that in order to properly compare these options and give a good answer, one would need to know: the likelihood of adding/deleting a store, the amount that the store will be used as a filter, how the data will be displayed, etc. Rather than breaking the link table up, though, it might be better to have store groups that you could link an item to so that stores that often carry the same items can be in a group and you only need one row and one extra join. Of course, you'd have to make sure stores' and store groups' ids are unique, unless you have a group for each single store, too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You left out one very important consideration in your pro and con lists: referential integrity. A fast database that lets you do easy queries is useless if it is full of broken data, that just lets you make mistakes faster and making mistakes is the last thing that humans need help with. The only option that allows foreign keys (i.e. referential integrity) is option (3).

A linking table is also the standard way to deal with this sort of thing and databases are usually designed to handle the standard use cases quite well.

As far as (1) goes, doing a `LIKE '%x%'` is going to do a table scan almost every time and a table scan is the last thing you ever want. You'd also have to make sure you have the `|` delimiter at the beginning and end of the strings or you'll need three LIKEs (or a regular expression) instead of just one. Some databases can use indexes for `LIKE 'x%'` but that doesn't apply to your case.

Approach (2) uses too many columns, your queries will be a mess and your tables will be too wide. You'd also have to worry about make sure each row in one table has a corresponding column in another table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first option can work well if the table will be having a small number of rows, it just doesn't make sense for this particular project. As for referential integrity, thanks for pointing that out, the research I've done since has been very helpful.

Comment: @Exit: I've actually used the (1)-approach a few times, but only when the column is an opaque blob as far as the database is concerned (i.e. the database only stores and retrieves it, never queries it). Foreign keys (and hence InnoDB in MySQL) are your friends: they make your data better even if they make your code a bit harder.

Answer (score -1):

Hey have you considered storing the value and fetching them using bitwise operation... 
like assigning every store an id this way:
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128...
just add one column in the item table itself to store single value like:
if item exists in stores with id 1, 4, 32 the field will store 37 in and while retrieving you can use & operation straight in the query to see if item exists in a particular store or not like this:

```
select * from item where store_id&1;
select * from item where store_id&4;
select * from item where store_id&32;
```

Comment: (1) Bit operations tend to lead to table scans. (2) There are only a limited number of bits available.